# 'Modify function to include m constant vectors'

Tags: python, linear-algebra

Seeking some help with some homework here. I've got the problem statement pasted in the link here: [Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dORSs.png)

(I will copy and paste the code here for the sake of easy readability and editability)

```
from numpy import dot, array
def gaussElimin(a,b):
    n = len(b)
    for k in range(0,n-1):
        for i in range(k+1,n):
            if a[i,k] != 0.0:
               lam = a[i,k]/a[k,k]
               a[i,k+1:n] = a[i,k+1:n] - lam*a[k,k+1:n]
               b[i] = b[i] - lam*b[k]
    for k in range(n-1,-1,-1):
        b[k] = (b[k] - dot(a[k,k+1:n],b[k+1:n]))/a[k,k]
    return b
```

The problem wants me to modify the function 'gaussElimin' so that it will work with m constant vectors. It then also provides two vectors for me to test to insure that the function works. I personally format them as the following:

```
a = [[2,-1,0],[-1,2,-1],[0,-1,2]]
a = array(a)

b = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
b = array(b)
```

I've already used the code once to do regular gauss eliminations (with the solution matrix being just a 1x3)
I'm very familiar with linear algebra, so I can use the inverse method to solve for it by hand (x in Ax=B, that is.)

However, I am at a loss at to what I need to change so that the program works. It appears to be applying the row operation to every value on that row, and the back substitution portion seems to be working fine as well.
Is there some syntax that I'm messing up?

Any help is very much appreciated.